# MySQL errors after a Wordpress clone

Tags: mysql

I've just cloned one of my wordpress installs on to a different domain, but each time I try to go in to certain setting screens through the dashboard, I get the following messages at the top of the screen...

```
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'adejones'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/adejones/public_html/PATH TO THEME/functions/admin-interface.php on line 111

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/adejones/public_html/PATH TO THEME/functions/admin-interface.php on line 111
```

Obviously there is a database connection as I wouldn't even get this far, but interested to know what is causing these errors and how to resolve them?

Thanks

Comment: Check file `functions/admin-interface.php`

Comment: Refer last answer in this page : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378976/php-mysql-real-escape-string-access-denied-for-user-www-datalocalhost

Comment: I don't think you should allow access to MySQL database blindly to fix this error. Any file in your theme folder should not ask for mysql access like that. If it's your code then you should use [better method](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) to interact with database. If it's not yours then check it what exactly it is doing.